# Why is an elliptic curve over a finite field symmetric about $y=p/2$?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I was reading [this tutorial](https://andrea.corbellini.name/2015/05/23/elliptic-curve-cryptography-finite-fields-and-discrete-logarithms/) about elliptic curves.

There are some example curves with $p=19$, $97$, $127$, $487$ etc, and they are all symmetric about $y=p/2$. Why is it the case?

Comment: The plot is symmetrical because if you write the curve as $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$ then the solutions have a symmetry $(x,y) \leftrightarrow (x,-y)$, which reduces mod $p$ gives $(x,y) \leftrightarrow (x,p-y)$ i.e. reflection above $y = p/2$.  There can be an exception when $y=0$, but then the number of points mod $p$ is even, which for many applications is undesirable (we want a the number of points mod $p$ to be prime).

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Thanks, but why when you reduce it modulo p, the symmetry becomes (x,y)↔(x,p-y)?

Comment: Not sure what kind of explanation you want.  That's what -y becomes mod p if 0 < y < p.  Note that p is 0 mod p so p-y is -y mod p.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies I see, thanks very much.